# C - Characters encoding without libiconv.so

Tags: c, character-encoding, buildroot

I had a board based on buildroot with the support for libiconv.so. I used this library to develop a module, running on this board, that needs to convert strings between different encondings (UTF-8, UTF-16BE, CP850,...). By evolving the development of the board, I introduced the BR2_ENABLE_LOCALE in buildroot and this forced me to remove the support  of the libiconv.so, which, hence, is no more present in the file system (see [this post](http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/buildroot/2011-July/044280.html) for details).
After doing this, of course my module did not work anymore, in particular, it compiles properly, but when calling the function `iconv_open()`, it always returns an "Invalid argument" error.
The commit message in the link I posted, states that with BR2_ENABLE_LOCALE activated, the libiconv.so is not necessary anymore, so my question is: how can I convert my strings now?

Comment: Which C run-time library implementation are you using including its version?

Comment: Thank you for reply. The operating system is Linux, it's not fully clear to me what do you mean with "C run-time library implementation"... maybe glib?

Comment: I mean something like glibc, uClibc, uClibc-ng, or musl libc. It will be part of the cross-compilation toolchain.

Comment: GLIBC_VERSION = 2.36-81
I'm trying to use
g_iconv_open("UTF-16BE", "UTF-8")
which fails and set the error to No such file or directory

Comment: Glibc uses external gconv module files, but there should be a set of standard system gconv modules installed along with the C library. I think you can control whether the modules get installed and which modules to install with `BR2_TOOLCHAIN_GLIBC_GCONV_LIBS_COPY` and `BR2_TOOLCHAIN_GLIBC_GCONV_LIBS_LIST`. The full set is ~8MiB on ARM, so you may want to select a smaller list of modules if space is tight.

Comment: Thank you so much, this definitely solved my problem! If you want to write it as answer, I will accept it